# Keep getting mails about xdebug

Tags: php, cron

I'm running Oneiric as a LAMP development server, and have xdebug installed. It works fine, but since I set up my email so that root mails are forwarded to my gmail, I keep getting the following:

subject:

```
Cron <root@pingu> [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

mail body

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Every 30 minutes. The cron job is in /etc/cron.d/php5 - it looks like it's to ensure sessions are automatically cleaned.

The cron job looks like it's needed - and is running a PHP script - but why is it complaining about xdebug, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you check the `apache` user's crontab, as well as the stuff in `/etc/cron.*`?

Comment: The cron job is in /etc/cron.d/php5. I'm pretty sure the problem isn't that the cronjob is running (it looks like it's a bit of useful maintenance), but that it's trying to load xdebug twice - that's the bit I need to fix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your php.ini settings; if you have a separate `xdebug.ini` file under `/etc/php5/conf.d` containing a `zend_extension=*.xdebug.so` line, it's possible that it already exists in the main cli/php.ini file too, so when it tries to load the second config file it'll produe the already loaded error message.

Comment: Yup, that was it. as well as in the /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini, it was also in the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini - removing the line from there fixed the problem.

Comment: It's also worth looking to see what modules/extensions are compiled in with `php -m`.  See http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have more then just a job loading `xdebug`.

Look for more lines inside your `/etc/cron.d/` folder files and inside `/etc/php5/conf.d` trying to load `xdebug.so`.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Unfortunately it's not really much help. Sure it's true that xdebug.so is loaded in /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini - but it needs to be in order for xdebug to run. it's just this one job that's complaining about loading it twice - all php commandline scripts, and webscripts are fine

Comment: Ehm, this answer is almost as good as the other one. +1.